# Android: Volley request is not working in released APK while works in debug

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have created a simple volley request for POST

```
//post request handler
    public void PostRequest(final int queryType, String url, final String jsonData) {
        StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                for (ApiRequestHandler commHandler : responseListeners) {
                    commHandler.responseHandler(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                for (ApiRequestHandler commHandler : errorListeners) {
                    commHandler.errorHandler(error);
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                return jsonData.getBytes();
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {

                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        getVolleyQueue().add(req);
    }
```

This method works when I send request in debug mode (Android device connected to Android Studio), while it does not work when I release the app and I get a 400 error.
I have added Internet permissions.

It is difficult to debug when app is released, I just tried to toast when the error is received. The stacktrace is like that, but of no help to me.

```
com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.a(Unknown Source:255),
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.b(Unknown Source:37),
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(Unknown Source:5)
```

I have spent like a day solving this, few of my pointers:

- I could see body being blank when request sent from release on server side, but prints data at APK level
- I also tried `jsonData.getBytes("utf-8");` but didn't work
- I am using `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'`

I also need some guidelines on better ways to debug released apks. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried debugging the release `buildType` in your project?
you can do so by setting the `release` build type and setting `debuggable true`. Then you can see logs of your APK in your development environment as if it was the release version.

Comment: Check also that the url you use start with https

Comment: @SomerandomITboy: Thanks, I could get my debug work using your hint!

Comment: @UserOne: I did check it already and was not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After little more digging, I could find the root cause:

The issue was because I have ProGuard enabled for release build type as `minifyEnabled true`. It compresses and obfuscates the code by various means like changing class names, variables, constants, etc.

Gson, uses dynamic key naming to make keys short.

To solve this, I used `@SerializedName("keyName")` annotation to let Gson know what to consider as the key.

For ex:

```
public class UserInfo {
    @SerializedName("user_name")
    public String userName;
    @SerializedName("mobile")
    public String mobile;
}
```

Hope this saves someone's day!

Comment: I am using FasterXML instead of Gson and faced same problem. On disabling "shrinkResources true" and "minifyEnabled true", code worked as expected but, incresing the apk size 4 times. Is there any equivalent solution for FasterXML?